# Improve SQL Query Performance after adding Unique Transaction clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that has optional parameters (pretty much all of them); if the parameter is not supplied, it needs to pull all data.

I have the following right now.

```
select * 
from myTableird
where 
    ird.tIS like COALESCE(null, ird.tIS) 
    and ird.InventoryDate = COALESCE(null, ird.InventoryDate)
    and ird.DateClosed = COALESCE(null, ird.DateClosed)
```

This runs very quickly, less than a second to generate the results.

I need to append code to only pull only the most recent record, for each repID. When I add the following code (last and statement), it just runs forever and times out after a few minutes. what did I do wrong? please help optimize the query, if possible, please explain so that I can learn, going forward. thank you!

```
select * 
from myTableird
where 
    ird.repID like COALESCE(null, ird.repID) 
    and ird.InventoryDate = COALESCE(null, ird.InventoryDate)
    and ird.DateClosed = COALESCE(null, ird.DateClosed)
    and ird.PeriodID in (SELECT MAX(PeriodID)    
                         FROM myTableird   
                         GROUP BY repID)
```

Comment: Change that to an INNER JOIN and you’ll see a big boost or use a window function like row_number in your query

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Comment: why do you have coalesce(null, ...) ?  that will always return the second parameter because the first is null. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . or am i missing something here?

Comment: @JohnBoker i have parameter names in my stored procedure, instead of "null" i should have said that. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

UGH. figured it out. all i had to do was post it. haha. anyway, here is what i came up with, it works instant now! please confirm that this is the best solution? Thanks!

```
select * from myTableird
inner join (ird.PeriodID in (SELECT MAX(PeriodID) as Pid   FROM myTableird   GROUP BY repID)) t2
on irdPeriodID = t2.PID
                                   where 
                                    ird.repID like COALESCE(null, ird.repID) 
                                    and ird.InventoryDate = COALESCE(null, ird.InventoryDate)
                                    and ird.DateClosed = COALESCE(null, ird.DateClosed)
```

Comment: Is `ird.PeriodID in` a left over? It doesn't look like valid syntax to me.